# TabbedPage in a ContentPage

Tags: xamarin.forms, syncfusion

I have a NavigationDrawer that I'm trying to keep in my MainPage, which also contains a TabbedPage. I want to keep the NavigationDrawer out of the tabbed pages, so that navigating between pages doesn't also animate the NavigationDrawer. How do I do this? I'm thinking along the lines of:

```xaml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WordbahnApp"
         xmlns:navigation="clr-namespace:Syncfusion.SfNavigationDrawer.XForms;assembly=Syncfusion.SfNavigationDrawer.XForms"
         x:Class="WordbahnApp.MainPage">

  <navigation:SfNavigationDrawer />

  <TabbedPage>
    <local:Browsing />
    <local:Reader />
    <local:Library />
    <local:LitFit />
  </TabbedPage>
</ContentPage>
```

Answer (score 2):

Query: How add NavigationDrawer and TabbedPage on MainPage(ContentPage).

We cannot add another page inside content page. We can add only views inside content page. Similarly, we cannot add tabbed page inside NavigationDrawer but we can add NavigationDrawer as content to TabbePage.

Regards,

Chozarajan P

Comment: If I try to add SfNavigationDrawer to the TabbedPage I get an error that the control isn't a ContentPage

Answer (score 1):

Inside the content page you can have only a view , you cannot put a page inside it .

can you drow what do you want to do ?